# Android: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, android, sorting, comparator

I'm seeing a lot of crashes on some Chinese Android phones for my app with the error: Comparison method violates its general contract!

I have read that it is something to do with the Collections.sort call.

The thing I'm not too sure about is if it is because of my custom Comparator or not.

Here is where the error occurs:

```
            if (!airports.isEmpty()) {
            Collections.sort(airports, new DistanceToAirportComparator(location));
            return airports.get(0);
        }
```

And the Comparator looks like this:

```
public class DistanceToAirportComparator implements Comparator<Airport> {

private final Location location;

public DistanceToAirportComparator(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}

@Override
public int compare(Airport airport1, Airport airport2) {
    Location loc1 = getLocation(airport1);
    Location loc2 = getLocation(airport2);
    return Double.compare(location.distanceTo(loc1), location.distanceTo(loc2));
}

private Location getLocation(Airport airport){
    Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    location.setLatitude(airport.getLocation().getLatitude());
    location.setLongitude(airport.getLocation().getLongitude());
    return location;
}
```

So I'm not too sure if the Comparator is messing something up or not or if I need to do the collections.sort call in a different way

Appreciate any help

Comment: Your sort call is correct. The problem might be that you don't compare  the two passed objects, but instead compare both to a third one. That's just a guess though.

Comment: If you check the Javadoc's for `Comparator` or `Comparable`, you'll see the contract. Test your comparator code separately to see if it's possible to break the contract with it.

Comment: Are you referring to loc1 & loc2? 
When you say 3rd object do you mean returning the Double.compare?

Comment: See @Derek Fung s answer, he explained it better. Your comparison might be unstable, because it is based on a third component, the location saved in the comparator.

Comment: @F43nd1r Thanks. Just not sure what I need to change in the code to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is talking about something like this:

Comparator should be correct in the sense that, if A > B and B > C, then A > C must be true.

So, it comes down to why it has such problem.
My guess is that because of the nature of Location, calculation of the distance is **unstable**

I would suggest you to pre-calculate the distance and use a Comparator on the result instead.

**Edit:**

Sample

```
private Airport sortByDistance(Location location) {
    List<Airport> airports;
    if (!airports.isEmpty()) {
        ArrayList<AirportWithDistance> distanceArrayList = new ArrayList<AirportWithDistance>(airports.size());
        for (Airport airport : airports) {
            distanceArrayList.add(new AirportWithDistance(airport, getDistance(airport, location)));
        }
        // replace start
        Collections.sort(distanceArrayList, new DistanceToAirportComparator());
        return airports.get(0).airport;
        // replace end
        //also seems u should replace the above to the line below instead, as you only wan min
        //return Collections.min(distanceArrayList, new DistanceToAirportComparator()).airport;
    }
    return null;
}


private static double getDistance(Airport airport, Location location){
    Location airportLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    airportLocation.setLatitude(airport.getLocation().getLatitude());
    airportLocation.setLongitude(airport.getLocation().getLongitude());
    return location.distanceTo(airportLocation);
}

public static class AirportWithDistance {
    Airport airport;
    double distance;

    AirportWithDistance(Airport airport, double distance) {
        this.airport = airport;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

}

public static class DistanceToAirportComparator implements Comparator<AirportWithDistance> {

    public DistanceToAirportComparator() {
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(AirportWithDistance airport1, AirportWithDistance airport2) {
        return Double.compare(airport1.distance, airport2.distance);
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say precalculate do you mean inside of the Compare method? Like instead of returning the compare I should get the closest one first and return that?

Comment: There are various way to do that, for example, you can add a field `distance` in class Airport, and calculate the distance and set the field value before sorting, and sort the list with comparator on the `distance` field. P.S. actually this will boost your performance as well, because reduced the number of times the distance is actually calculated.

Comment: Not sure what way to do that really.
I mean, in the Airport class, that just has a Location of the airport, but the distance is supposed to be a distance between 2 airports, so I can't have the distance in the Airport class can I? Since I don't know what the airport to compare to would be?

Comment: Actually you should try it first and ask on the problem you actually faced, but anyway I am giving you an example this time. Also, please check that seems you don't need `Collections.sort()` but `Collections.min()`

Comment: some amendment in the code, you need to get the airport by `.airport` after sort

Comment: Thanks. What I meant was, in the Airport class what is the distance going to be? The Airport class is just a representation of an airport, so it has a location, but I'm not sure what the distance can be since it doesn't have a second position to get the distance from.

Comment: in terms of OO, this is wrong to add inside airport, but as a dirty fix, it does the job. If you want it to be more meaningful in OO, you can see my solution, but this should be figured out by yourself. Anyway, just check the solution.

Comment: Ah right okay thanks for the help. Looking over your code again it makes more sense. Appreciate that

Comment: Mark it as answer if this answered your question.